# Different hyperlink of citation

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, links

[image]

I use the below command for package `hyperref`

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

It links with a underline shown in right side of the uploaded image.

How to put the link on citation with a box, shown in the left side of the image?

Comment: Those boxes partly depend on your viewer (mupdf for example doesn't show them at all).